# Best datastore algorithm for 2d vector graphics

Tags: algorithm, opengl, graphics, vector, 2d

I'm working on what I hope will be a very simple to use but powerful 2D cross platform CAD package. I know there are a few of these around already, but I'm doing this more for a learning experience than anything else.

I am using OpenGL for my rendering and I want to be able to highlight each entity as the mouse moves over it. I have algorithms for finding the nearest point on an entity, etc., but I don't want to scan through the entire datastore of entities for each movement.

I've looked at quadtrees, kd-trees, etc. but where I'm lost is how those can be used to narrow the focus for an entire entity. Most of the examples I've seen seem to be "point" oriented. I'm assuming I would want to index based on the bounding rectangle, then do nearest point searches for those entities within that rectangle.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for this?

Answer (score 1):

Thinking "Kd tree" goes into the right direction. Now you've to go one step further and extend your points into multidimensional primitives which have a position, and additional, parameters. Kd meand "K dimensions" after all.

So in the case of circles, or circular arcs you would store the center position in the first two dimensions of in the tree, and then the radius in the third dimension (for a set of 2d primitives). And for all other primitives, that are not circular, just assume a circular bounding region.

For linear primitives you might want to look into BSP trees. And of course you can combine the concept of Kd with BSP, like using Kd like nodes for curved primitives and BSP for primitives bounded by linear convex segments.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for something like [R-trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree), which are trees based on axis-oriented bounding boxes in which (unlike K-d trees) the boxes for sibling subtrees are permitted to overlap.  If I recall correctly, there are a number of variations based on different update heuristics.

A definitive reference on spatial datastructures, which includes much on R-trees and their relatives:

- *Foundations of Multidimensional and Metric Data Structures*, by Hanan Samet

Comment: I just looked at some info here and I do like this option. Specifically, it looks like R*Trees are a good fit. There seem to be a few good options out there for C++.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind spatial partitioning is to reduce the number of tests (and their computational needs) you need to perform in order to get a subset of primitives that can be tested using finer methods.

You're right about having to use the bounding box of the entire entity and first determining what entity is under the mouse when it is being moved.

You also have some other options:

1. Spatial hashing as shown in [this](http://www.serpentine.com/blog/2007/01/11/two-dimensional-spatial-hashing-with-space-filling-curves/) link. This allows you to perform a linear (or hierarchical) search using a low-cost distance function (this for 2D, but easy to extend to 3D).
2. OpenGL picking - if you've implemented a good-enough culling method in your rendering code, you could use [OpenGL picking](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/picking/) to quickly determine the current object under your mouse. Provided your culling code is fast, this will be fast too.

And many others I'm sure I'm missing - I will add them as I think of more. :) Hope this helps!

Comment: I'll have to do some more research on the spatial hashing. Looks like they are using Hilbert curves and I'm not very familiar with those.  I did look at opengl picking, the thing is though, this option still means I have to render the entities to a back-plane so I'm still faced with needing to narrow down the number of entities I render. At this point, I'm leaning towards Comingstorm's idea above about r-trees.